# Как сделать переход из одной части в другую C#

Tags: c#, консоль

У меня есть система проверки регистрации

```
    bool isPerrmised = false;            
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("Проверка регистрации...");
if (isPerrmised)
{
Console.WriteLine("Вы вошли");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Хотите купить подписку? (Цена - " + price + " )" );
string yorn = Console.ReadLine();
switch (yorn)
{
default:
Console.WriteLine("Сумма пополнения:");
string symmapopolneniya = Console.ReadLine();
int symmapopolneniyaready = Convert.ToInt32(symmapopolneniya);
Console.WriteLine("Проверка платежа...");
int count = 0;
while (count < 100)
{
count++;
Console.WriteLine("Проверка - " + count + " %");
}
Console.WriteLine("Проверка платежа...");
int newbalance = symmapopolneniyaready;
Console.WriteLine("Ваш текущий баланс - " + newbalance + " рублей");
Console.WriteLine("Подписка оформлена. Ваш баланс - " + (newbalance - 
price));
isPerrmised = true;
Console.ReadKey();
return;
case "N":
Console.WriteLine("Вы отказались от пополнения");
Console.ReadKey();
break;
}
}
```

Как сделать чтобы после пополнения и изменения переменной isPerrmised на true нас отправляло в начало на проверку?

Comment: цикл?...........

Comment: Отформатированный код гораздо легче было бы читать.

Comment: Через цикл `while`. string symmapopolneniya
Не надо так называть переменные.

Comment: @aepot Согласен, еще нужно норм названия делать, а не `summapopoleniya`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй goto

```
Link:
Console.WriteLine("Проверка регистрации...");
if (isPerrmised)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Вы вошли");
}
goto Link;
```

или через цикл

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   bool b = true;
   while (b)
   {
     int price = 100;
     bool isPerrmised = false;
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
     Console.WriteLine("Проверка регистрации...");
     if (isPerrmised)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Вы вошли");
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Хотите купить подписку? (Цена - " + price + " ) (Yes/No)");
        string yorn = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (yorn)
        {
           case "Yes":
           Console.WriteLine("Сумма пополнения:");
           string symmapopolneniya = Console.ReadLine();
           int symmapopolneniyaready = Convert.ToInt32(symmapopolneniya);
           Console.WriteLine("Проверка платежа...");
           int count = 0;
           while (count < 100)
           {
               count++;
               Console.WriteLine("Проверка - " + count + " %");
           }
           Console.WriteLine("Проверка платежа...");
           int newbalance = symmapopolneniyaready;
           Console.WriteLine("Ваш текущий баланс - " + newbalance + " рублей");
           Console.WriteLine("Подписка оформлена. Ваш баланс - " + (newbalance - price));
           isPerrmised = true;
           break;

           case "No":
                Console.WriteLine("Вы отказались от пополнения");
                b = false;
                break;

           default:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы не выбрали ничего");
                b = false;
                break;
        }
     }
  }
       Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Эх, хотел про goto схохмить, но сайт отключился на обслуживание. Повезло ящерику, успел исправиться, а то бы до скончания времён бегал от разъярённых программистов. :)